# Socket.io - Terminal returning data as "null"

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

### I'm building a forum app using reactjs, nodejs, express and mongoDB, where users can create account, login and then post a post text. I want this post to be displayed instantly To all others users, for that i am using socket.io server.

I would appreciate if you check my whole project here in github: (https://github.com/darkpsinight/forum)

However, whenever a user login or connect to the app, i get this **null** in socket terminal:

```
Connected user.✅
null
```

I tried to investigate this **null** message, and i discovered that **data** is returning null.

How to make data returns data of **createdPostsocket** instead of null ?

---

### Edit:

**createdPostsocket** is initialized as null, and my catch statement returns **null**, so either i am *not assigning a value* to **createdPostsocket** or i am throwing an error in my promise.

Meanwhile, i already assigned a value in Slice at fulfilled case :

```
[createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
console.log(action.payload);
window.location.reload(false);
state.createdPostsocket= action.payload.data.data
}
```

Which means **createdPostsocket** assigned the value of **payload.data.data**, right?

---

**My codes:**

*- Back:*

**app.js** (socket server)

```
const io = require("socket.io")(4000, {
cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
},
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('Connected user.✅');

socket.on('addPost', data => {
    console.log(data);     //returning null in terminal
    io.emit('newPost', data)
})

socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Disconnected user.⛔️');
});
});
```

*- Front:*

**postsSlice.js:**

```
const initialState = {
posts: [],
createdPostsocket: null
};

const postsSlice = createSlice({
name: "posts",
initialState,

reducers: {},

extraReducers: {

    //Create http request 3 cases
    [createPost.pending]: (state, action) => {

    },

    [createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload);
        window.location.reload(false);
        state.createdPostsocket= action.payload.data.data
    },

    [createPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
        
    },
},
});
export const { } = postsSlice.actions;
export const selectPosts = (state) => state.posts
export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

**index.jsx:**

```
const posts = useSelector(selectPosts)
const socket = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:4000")
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.emit("addPost", posts.createdPostsocket);
    console.log (posts.createdPostsocket)      //returning null in console developper
}, [posts.createdPostsocket])
```

**postsAPI.js**

```
import { axiosInstance } from "../../config/axios";
import { requests } from "../../config/requests";

//post service
export const PostsService = {

  // Create post request
  create: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return axiosInstance
      .post(requests.postapi.create, data, { credentials: "include" })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  },
};
```

---

*- back:*

**controller.js:**

```
module.exports = {
create: (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        user: req.user.sub,
        text: req.body.text,
        /* image: req.file && req.file.filename */
    }

    console.log(data)    //returning user and text

    const t = new post(data)
    t.save().then(t => t
        .populate('user')
        .then(post => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'post created',
                data: post
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: 'post not created',
                data: null
            })
        })
    )
},
```

}

Comment: if `posts.createdPostsocket` is returning `null` on the frontend, this is clearly not an issue with socket.io but rather with your frontend logic

Comment: you sure it is frontend not backend? like problem in my controller.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `window.location.reload(false);` so you wont lose your data. `window.location.reload(false);` will reload your page and delete all the data. However it is not recommanded to use vanilla JavaScript to call the reload method to tell the browser to reload the current page and you will loose any data.